# Running an executable in SCRIPT with several files as input

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, executable

I'm a beginner using script and am trying to make a simple script to run an executable named "main" with several files located in subdirectories as inputs, producing one output file for each input. When I try this program:

```
exec=./main ;

 for d in ./subdir/subdir2/*/ ; do

  (cd "$d" && for f in *.xml ; do (echo "$f" && ("$exec" < "$f" > "${f%.*}_output.csv")); done ); done
```

But it gives me:

```
./script_parser.txt: line 11: ./main: No such file or directory
```

I've tried only putting exec=/main and exec=main but with no success. With the echo code I see that all input files in my subdirectories are being found.

So how can I maybe store the original directory where my main is and run it with those files? Notice that I don't want to put the absolute path(like ~/User/etc..) since I want this script to run on other machines as well.

If it changes anything, I'm using a MacBook.

Comment: Error in line 11? You only posted 5. You're missing a shebang in line 1 but tagged the question "bash". How do you invoke it, with "bash ./script_parser.txt" explicitly?

Comment: yes, the script will be run by the user using ./script_parser.txt

Comment: And next week you comment on the 2 other issues? [mcve] sil vous plait. Btw.: Since the user will run the script in the future and we so far never experienced users from the future, the question is still open, which invocation triggered above cited error. We rarely ask such questions without reason.